# Insert sorted elements with pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers, insert

I have a class named Client, with the next attribute:
string Id = "XXXX"
Where "XXXX" are 4 chars. (for example, "ABCD").

I've an already sorted list with clients, from "AAAA" to "IIII":

```
Dni: 56495745V - ID: AAAA
Dni: 88257733V - ID: BBBB
Dni: 85221964H - ID: CCCC
Dni: 91761636P - ID: DDDD
Dni: 75636147A - ID: FFFF
Dni: 14987955M - ID: GGGG
Dni: 43985567E - ID: HHHH
Dni: 61269954R - ID: IIII
```

I want to insert the next client:
Dni: 48879625W - ID: EEEE

aux is a pointer to a node of the list, that contains a clients and a pointer to the next element.
In order to not make it more complex, instead of using a loop i'm gonna force the aux pointer point to position 4 (client with Id: "DDDD"):

```
pnodocolacliente aux; // Pointer to NodoColaCliente.
    NodoColaCliente nodoCliente = NodoColaCliente(cliente); // Node with the client that I want to insert, with Id="EEEE".
    aux = first; // Position 1 (Id: "AAAA")
    aux = aux->next; // Position 2(Id: "BBBB")
    aux = aux->next; // Position 3 (Id: "CCCC")
    aux = aux->next; // Position 4 (Id: "DDDD")
    cout << "Aux: " + aux->client.toString() << endl; // Returns the client with Id="DDDD"
    cout << "Aux.next: " + aux->next->client.toString() << endl; // Returns the client with Id="DDDD".
    nodoCliente.next= aux->next; // nodoCliente.next points to the node that contains the client with Id="FFFF".
    aux->next=&nodoCliente; // I want to make the pointer of the node that contains the client DDDD to point to nodoCliente, that has the client with Id EEEE.
```

However, when I execute the last line, the executable crashes. If i've it commented, it works but obviusly I don't finally insert.
What am I doing wrong?

I've tried this too:

```
pnodocolacliente aux;
pnodocolacliente nodoCliente;
nodoCliente->client=client; //nodoCliente contains the client I want to insert.
aux = primero;
aux = aux->siguiente;
aux = aux->siguiente;
aux = aux->next;
cout << "Aux: " + aux->client.toString() << endl;
cout << "Aux.next: " + aux->next->client.toString() << endl;
nodoCliente->next= aux->next;
aux->next = nodoCliente;
```

But it crashes this time on both last two lines.
Image of what I want to do:
[Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBwTo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does code crash on 2 different lines?

Comment: If I comment the first one, it works until the second one. If I comment the second one, it crashes on the first one.

Comment: `NodoColaCliente nodoCliente = NodoColaCliente(cliente);...aux->next=&nodoCliente;` -- `nodoCliente` is a local variable, and you're storing a pointer to it?  When that local goes out of scope, that pointer will point to garbage.  It looks like you have the same issue as [this recent poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237701/binary-search-tree-having-issues-with-insert-function)

Comment: @UrbanWildCat `aux->next=&nodoCliente` Change that to `aux->next= new NodoColoCliente;`.  Does the issue go away?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yiep that worked. Thank you soooo much, I've been struggling with this for at least 3 hours. Seems like it crashed becouse I pointed to the local variable, and when the function ended the pointer point to garbage as you said. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: @UrbanWildCat -- Probably won't post an answer, as the solution is what I linked to in the comments.  You can go there and see the explanation of the issue.